# Extended Android Floating Button

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I developed Android Application and I want to use extended floating button like floating button on Path Application in my layout. I hope someone can give me example about the code how to make this things. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a detailed tutorial on how to create a good extended floating button with animations https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-floating-action-button-animations.html

Comment: It's working nicely. Thank you so much for helping me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hellooooo"
            app:icon = "@drawable/pass_resource_here"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton>
```

Comment: You can add icon and text at the same time in the new ExtendedFloatingActionButton.

Comment: Do you know how to increase the duration while FAB is extanding/shrinking?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library and modify it to your liking by using the sam ple project in the library

https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu