# How use the real Floating Action Button (FAB) Extended?

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

To remove any doubts or thoughts about duplicate: on [Material Design](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#extended-fab) is defined what is "extended".

[image: FAB - Extended FAB]

But most of the people confuses "extended" with "[Type of Transition: Speed Dial](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#types-of-transitions)", what make hard to find solutions. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497274/extended-android-floating-button)

[image: FAB - Type of Transition: Speed Dial]

**Question**
So what I'm looking forward is how setup the FAB with text and a extended size.

Today my code is like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/maps_main_distance_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/str_distance_btn"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

But my button look like this:

[image]

No text and no right format. I'm using it in a Constraint Layout.

Comment: It says on that page you linked that the extended FAB for Android is not yet available. Maybe try using a custom view to approximate the effect.

Comment: @LeoAso but that is for a example, right? What I got it is that they didn't make a code example yet, but it already exist...

Comment: I don't think so. It seems that page links to the actual implementations of the components, not just examples. If you check the links marked "Code Available", you'll see the documentation for the components. If you click the Android link, you'll see that it has not been implemented.

Comment: It has just been added to the Material components Android library as planned work, you can see the issue raised in Github - https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/79

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Add the dependencies in your Gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

in your xml file:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:text="Create"
            app:icon="@drawable/outline_home_24" />
```

Comment: Give this person a medal !!

Comment: Don't forget to put material component theme, like 'Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar'

Comment: If your activity theme not inherit 'Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar' , you must include  android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar" as an attribute of the button. Otherwise there is a chance to get layout inflate exception

Comment: This does not seem to work with material v `1.1.0` (no alpha) or a newer version (I tried v `1.2.1`). Why do I need `1.1.0-alpha04` for this to work? Is there anywhere I can verify/check if there are newer implementations I can use that include this?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

You can create a utility class that animates a `MaterialButton` to an Extended `FloatingActionButton` using a `ConstraintLayout`. You'll first need to declare the two states of the `MaterialButton` in xml, and then use the `TransitionManager` to animate between them.

You can read a medium post about it [here](https://medium.com/@Tunji_D/creating-an-expandable-floating-action-button-in-android-6626b968559e), in the meantime, I'll add bits of relevant code here.

Collapsed FAB state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/extend_fab_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_fab"
    android:elevation="8dp">

    <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:cornerRadius="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Extended FAB State:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/extend_fab_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_fab">

    <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cornerRadius="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Background Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <corners android:radius="56dp" />
</shape>
```

And relevant Java Expansion code:

```
private void setExtended(boolean extended, boolean force) {
    if (isAnimating || (extended && isExtended() && !force)) return;

    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    set.clone(container.getContext(), extended ? R.layout.fab_extended : R.layout.fab_collapsed);

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(container, new AutoTransition()
            .addListener(listener).setDuration(150));

    if (extended) button.setText(currentText);
    else button.setText("");

    set.applyTo(container);
}
```

Comment: I see this but how it's the behaviour when a snackBar message appears? it moves up? cover the message or get covered?

Comment: @Canato the FAB will move up like it does in the Support Library

Comment: The point I didn't get is why you're not simply using FlaotingActonButtonExtended of material design library

Comment: @FARID if you pay attention for the date of the answer you can see that was not launch yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/robertlevonyan/customFloatingActionButton) to do that. (I used another way)
But I used a [FancyButton](https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons) to create a round and awesome button in coordinator layout as below:

```
    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
    android:id="@+id/actMain_btnCompare"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/fab_transformation_sheet_behavior"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    fancy:fb_borderColor="@color/white"
    fancy:fb_borderWidth="3dp"
    fancy:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    fancy:fb_radius="20dp"
    fancy:fb_text="مقایسه محصول"
    fancy:fb_textColor="@color/white"
    fancy:fb_textGravity="center"
    fancy:fb_textSize="13sp" />
```

and result is:

[image]

That can have icon in it (see [FancyButton](https://github.com/medyo/Fancybuttons)).

with    `app:layout_behavior="@string/fab_transformation_sheet_behavior"` it acts like fab as below:

[image]

Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

The short answer: set the background to a rect with rounded corners, rather than an oval.  Then set the dimension of the radius to half that of the height of the button.

How I actually did it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/maps_main_distance_btn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/floating_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_button_height"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_background_expanded"
    android:text="@string/str_distance_btn"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

drawable/btn_background_expanded.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
            <corners
                android:radius="@dimen/floating_button_radius"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: I tried now, but didn't work for me. Can you say what dimens are you using? and if you have a picture of the result? Thanks.

Comment: @Canato this is not a solution. Android won't let you define a custom background for FAB the way this guy has done. He has probably believed it will apply to FAB like other views but not :))

Comment: @FARID thanks, I didn't put this as solution, I even said that didn't work for me

Comment: @CanatovI didn't mean you. I meant the guy who posted this answer